# Bootstrap 4 Flex Layout for App

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I create this layout using Bootstrap 4.  I did this once myself before 4 was out with Flexbox, but I want to use Bootstrap 4 now.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div>Fixed Header Height</div>
  <div>This should take full available height of screen</div>
  <div>Fixed Footer Height</div>
</div>
```

What class do I use on the center div to make it take up the full height of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create fixed `header` at top, fixed `footer` at bottom and rest space to be used as `content`. This can be achieved using bootstrap very easily. Here is sample layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Resources -->
        <style type='text/css'>
            .header {
                height: 60px;
            }
            .footer {
                height: 80px;
            }
            .app-content {
                margin-top: 60px;
                margin-bottom: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="vertical-layout">
        <div class="fixed-top header bg-success">
            <!-- Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="content app-content">
            <!-- Content -->
        </div>
        <footer class="footer footer-dark fixed-bottom bg-info">
            <!-- Content -->
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

If this does not solve your problem, than using flex you can use code as:

```
 <style>
    .full {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .fill {
        flex: 1;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Using `flex: 1` will make it fill the available space. The content as:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column full">
    <div>Fixed Header Height</div>
    <div class="fill">
        This should take full available height of screen
    </div>
    <div>Fixed Footer Height</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write some css like applying `min-height` of flex div to `100vh` and then use `flex:1` to the middle div....

..as I am aware to bootstrap4 there is such no class to set `flex:1` and `height:screen-height` to the div

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.navbar {
  background: #ccc;
}

.d-flex.flex-column {
  height: 100vh;
}

.full-height {
  background: black;
  flex: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="navbar header">Fixed Header Height</div>
  <div class="full-height"><br><br>This should take full available height of screen</div>
  <div class="navbar footer">Fixed Footer Height</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appeared to work, but the header and footer are actually on top of the center.  The below answer did work correctly.

Comment: @GregGum See...the height of the `header` and `footer` are not fixed...their height will be calculated by the inner content...so I think giving a fixed margin top and bottom in the center  will not work...I updated my answer without using `fixed` position